# CYLOR Disclaimer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The previous incarnation of this site had the following disclaimer at the top, in red:

> Like Wikipedia, mi.yodeya makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice.
>   Treat mi.yodeya information like it came from a crowd of your friends.

I don't see anything like that here yet, presumably because we're using a generic beta template. Is there any way to get it on?

(CYLOR: [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR))

---

Addition from Isaac Moses:

I asked SE about this when we were getting ready for migration, and the response was that the moderators should be able to add this as a system message. In fact, I have that ability now, but system messages expire after a maximum of 48 hours, so it's not really a sustainable technique.

I wonder if SE could either grant us an exception to the 48-hour rule or insert the appropriate HTML (included below) permanently at the top of the site.

This basic issue is very important to me and to many other users of this site, as discussed in [this early meta-question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/409/make-for-yourself-a-website). The red disclaimer was an important part of what made us comfortable with the Jewish crowd-Q&A enterprise.

```
<p style="color:#ff0000"><center><strong>
Like
<a style="color:#ff0000" href = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:General_disclaimer>Wikipedia</a>,
Judaism.SE makes <i>no guarantee of validity</i>, and does not offer professional
(particularly rabbinic) advice.<br>Treat information from this site like it came
from a crowd of your friends.
</strong></center></p>
```

Comment: +1 because this is a great (necessary to maintain integrity) idea.

Comment: +1: I also urge the SE folks to grant this feature request.

Comment: I strongly agree with Isaac.

Answer (score 9):

**Note —** The CYLOR Disclaimer now appears at the top of the right menu per Isaac's answer here:

[Professional advice disclaimer (post-launch re-request)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3883/409)

Answer (score 6):

I was just on browsing http://skeptics.stackexchange.com as a visitor (i.e. not logged in) and say the following disclaimer on the bottom of several sourceless answers:

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

[image: screenshot of skeptic site]

Isn't that what we want to do with CYLOR? Let's find out how they did it and implement it here.

I would say to only put it under a question with the halacha tag (as opposed to every answer). I also think it's fine if it only shows up for people who are not logged in, since members should know this already.

Comment: That's a standard ["post notice"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners) that mods can add at will. I've [proposed](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/401/post-notices-for-halacha-questions) a Halacha-oriented one of these [twice](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/professional-advice-disclaimer-post-launch-re-request).

Comment: For examples of these standard notices in use, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8851 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14218.

Answer (score 5):

I've inserted this disclaimer into the editable part of the FAQ as a half measure.

---

UPDATE July 20, 2011: I also added this disclaimer to the tag wiki for [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law).

---

UPDATE September 1, 2011: Now that there are other sites facing similar issues, I've [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/wanted-a-standard-way-for-a-site-to-have-a-prominent-professional-advice-disclai) on MSO that SE create a way for us all to put up a prominent disclaimer for all users.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how the back-end works here, and I don't know how the owners will take to it, but why can't we have a cron job to put a "CYLOR" message at the top (like we did with the contest)?

Comment: Community moderators don't have access to the server. That said, I suppose we could use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org)....

Comment: @tom, It's an idea worth considering. I'd much prefer that SE implement what I suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/wanted-a-standard-way-for-a-site-to-have-a-prominent-professional-advice-disclai). They haven't marked it as declined, so there's hope ...

Comment: @tom, that's essentially what Selenium does, from what I understand.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I'm not sure adding it to the bulletin is the best idea, but these comments are not the place to discuss it: propose it in a separate question here on Meta if you wish.