# Replace "does not offer" link in /about with canonical link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-content, about-page

Now that we have a canonical FAQ entry for "[Can I consult Mi Yodeya as I would a rabbi?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi)," I recommend that our [About page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/about)  link to it in the second paragraph, where it says "but does not offer personalized, professional advice," instead of to [an older, more deliberative Q&A](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/perhaps-the-community-moderators-should-enact-a-more-strict-policy-regarding-hal/314#314).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds good to me. I've implemented this change.

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't you use the [full form of the link](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi), including title?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Fewer characters? That's what came up when I clicked `share`?

Comment: I'll buy the first explanation, though I don't quite understand the motivation in this context. The second is partially false. In any case, the links that include titles are nice, especially for user documentation, since they provide for more informative rollover text.