# How quick should we be to close vs help

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

There are times when a certain question is proposed to be off topic. See the comments to [Who were the original users of Ktav Ashuri?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66590/6591) for a recent discussion.

There is an obvious quick fix to keep that particular question on topic.

How quick should we be to close it, leaving the OP wondering exactly how to fix it,  vs offering the easy solution to the OP?

Should there be more of a leeway for an OP who is new to the site? Give them some kind of learning curve?

Should it matter how popular (by up-votes) the question is?
I'm not suggesting to keep off topics open due to their popularity, but should we be offering more help to fix a questionable post due to its popularity?

Comment: If you have ability, time, and inclination to help, then help. (Although [not always](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/what-to-do-with-fixable-request-for-psak-questions?lq=1) when the problem is that it's a request for *pesak*.) There's no way to force that to happen by rules, though, since rules can't make people have ability, time, and inclination. See also, [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66590/who-were-the-original-users-of-ktav-ashuri#comment202947_66590) by DoubleAA.

Comment: I think that question that are hostile to the Jews or judaism should be quickly suppressed with a standard reason. "Let us make no mistake as to what is at issue here". there are dozen of "why Jews do not accept the acrobat?" it is unbearable.

Comment: MOD NOTE: The above referenced comment of mine is now deleted. It said: `Close if it is closeworthy. Bring something into scope if you want to. (That's my rule of thumb. You can ask on Meta if you think it should be different. My logic is 1) I can't leave closeworthy things open, 2) I can't be expected to try and bring everything into scope somehow.)`

Answer (score 3):

The ease of the fix is not reason to implement it, as there are plenty of bad posts which wouldn't be of much value even if they could be brought on topic. (Adding the bracketed phrase to "I saw the word משה [in a Jewish text]. What does it mean?" doesn't produce a question of significant value, IMO.)

It's not anyone's *responsibility* to fix other people's questions. If you want the open version of the question to exist, and you feel up for doing the work to get it there, then כל הכבוד go ahead. How much effort you put in will depend on how nice you are feeling, how busy you are, and how much you think the question will be worth when your done.

I'm not trying to discourage [being nice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). We just need to recognize this for what it is.

Comment: Perhaps wasn't clear. I'm not suggesting to fix it ourselves. I'm suggesting to tell the OP explicitly what they would need to do to keep it on topic.

Comment: @user6591 Same thing. If you have the time/inclination/etc. and want the question fixed, then be my guest.

Comment: I think that a positive spirit and a propensity to help are the natural tendency in a jewish website,  in a jewish Judaism website in a jewish Judaism public website

Comment: @kouty Halevai that we could help everyone always.