# Can I consult Mi Yodeya as I would a rabbi?

Tags: support, faq, scope, halacha

Does Mi Yodeya offer personal guidance in response to practical questions about Jewish law or attitudes, as a rabbi would?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It does not!

An early version of this site had the following important disclaimer at the top, in red:

> Like Wikipedia, mi.yodeya makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat mi.yodeya information like it came from a crowd of your friends.

And we mean it! On a website like this you can get some interesting information and discussion, but it won't be tailored to your specific situation, where you stand in Jewish observance, etc.

Therefore, the community has decided to include the following in [the Help Center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information you find here as if it came from a crowd of your friends.** ([Source](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/2))
>
> - Questions that appear to be requests for personal practical advice will be either edited to more general wording or closed ([more information](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1734)).
> - For more on why it's important to take personal questions of Jewish practice to your Rabbi, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

Similarly, the following appears near the top of most pages on Mi Yodeya:

> Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but *[does not offer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

---

<sup>This answer was based on the answers and comments at https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/312, https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3883, and other sources; portions were copypasted from https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/48, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/414, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/412, and https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3883. See there for contributors.</sup>

Comment: Also worth noting that sometimes the accepted answers here are just wrong. (Rare, but it happens.) Popular opinion isn't always factual.