# Disclaimer box still has http:// and old meta link

Tags: bug, front-page

Mi Yodeya has a disclaimer box on the side of the page, saying that

> Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but *[does not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

The "from your rabbi" link is still `http://`, and the "does not offer" link links to `http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734` instead of `https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Looks like it's been fixed, finally.